# .NET Core Web Api Loading Nested Entities

Tags: database, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I have a db model that looks like:

```
    public CallTrackers()
    {
        CallTrackerCallerTelns = new HashSet<CallTrackerCallerTelns>();
        CallTrackerClients = new HashSet<CallTrackerClients>();
        CallTrackerFlwups = new HashSet<CallTrackerFlwups>();
        CallTrackerHistory = new HashSet<CallTrackerHistory>();
    }
```

With my GetAll() I am loading everything fine except for CallTrackerClients has 3 nested objects that I can't retrieve:

```
    public CallTrackerClients()
    {
        CallTrackerClientAdvice = new HashSet<CallTrackerClientAdvice>();
        CallTrackerClientOffences = new HashSet<CallTrackerClientOffences>();
        CallTrackerClientSureties = new HashSet<CallTrackerClientSureties>();
    }
```

I am trying:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<CallTrackers> GetAll()
    {
        return _context.CallTrackers
            .Include(log => log.CallTrackerClients)
                .ThenInclude(c => c.CallTrackerClientAdvice)
            .Include(log => log.CallTrackerCallerTelns)
            .Include(log => log.CallTrackerFlwups)
            .Include(log => log.CallTrackerHistory)
            .ToList();
    }
```

The above works but I need to get the Sureties and Offences as well. When I try `.ThenInclude(c => c.CallTrackerClientOffences)`I get some 'does not contain definition' error.

Any ideas how to get the two remaining collections that are part of CallTrackerClients?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You always have to start from the parent entity.

```
    return _context.CallTrackers
        .Include(log => log.CallTrackerClients)
            .ThenInclude(c => c.CallTrackerClientAdvice)
        // this
        .Include(log => log.CallTrackerClients)
            .ThenInclude(c => c.CallTrackerClientOffences)
        // and this
        .Include(log => log.CallTrackerClients)
            .ThenInclude(c => c.CallTrackerClientSureties)
        .Include(log => log.CallTrackerCallerTelns)
        .Include(log => log.CallTrackerFlwups)
        .Include(log => log.CallTrackerHistory)
        .ToList();
```